# Fastlane command to update url and bundle identifier

Tags: ruby, build, plist, fastlane

How can i update the url and bundle-identifier for the below plist using fastlane ?
While using the update_info_plist command from fastlane its asking for a block , i dont understand what it is.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://server/cache/app.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.demo</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>CavionNovus</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you try with set_info_plist_value? https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/set_info_plist_value/

Comment: it will add a new key value on the bottom of the xml only , not updating the existing url

Comment: It updates it if it exists

Comment: ok , then it couldnt find the exisitng key within the items > assets . while am trying the set command it add new entry on the bottom